# Regex : Take all except one condition

Tags: python, regex

Looking for a quick answer here.

I have the following text :

```
2018-09-15 15:59:41,311 INFO  [Timer-0]-dashboard.PSDashboard: getProcessSummary -->  processing output line
[32mOk: {"status":200,"name":"xya.com","version":"1.1.2.371","cis":"online","tagline":""}[0m
2018-09-15 15:59:40,106 INFO  [Timer-0]-util.SSHUtil: Connecting to host [10.60.9.59] using provided credentials.
2018-09-15 15:59:40,209 INFO  [Timer-0]-util.SSHUtil: Connected to host [10.60.9.29] using provided credentials.
2018-09-15 15:59:40,209 INFO  [Timer-0]-util.SSHUtil: Connected to host 10.60.9.34 using provided credentials.
```

Regex i have :

```
[^(?<=version":")(.*)(?="cis)](\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

As you can see i am trying to avoid capturing `1.1.2.371` as its not really an IP but the problem is, the capturing group is not good as its picking up the Square bracket as well.

Comment: We know what you don't want to capture but it is unclear what you *are* trying to capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only false flag IP address present in your log file would be a version number, then you may use a negative lookbehind assertion to check for this:

```
(?<!version":")(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

### Demo

There are other ways we could have phrased the pattern.  If IP addresses of interest would always follow the text `host`, then we could have checked for that instead.  Also, if there are other preceding words covering cases for false flag IP addresses, we could update the negative lookbehind to cover those cases as well.

Comment: Wait, i am trying NOT to capture that bit of information :)

Comment: Then edit your question and tell us what you are trying to here.  I answered based on what your pattern seemed to imply.

Comment: As you can see i am trying to avoid capturing 1.1.2.371 as its not really an IP. So, i am using the Hat symbol to avoid capturing that information.

Comment: Are you trying to capture lines which contain IP addresses, or maybe IP addresses in such lines?

Comment: I want to capture all IP addresses except the ones that not actually an IP address, so as per my input lines, line 2 contains a version information which gets picked up because its in IP address format but because its not really an IP address, i am trying to avoid capturing it but somehow my regex is un-stable (the one that i posted in my original post)